# Minimize the number of elements to complete the maximum amount of sets.

Tags: optimization

Consider a set of distinct elements $\{a_1, a_2, a_3,\dots, a_n\}$ (the universe) and a collection of sets  $S= \{ S_1, S_2, S_3,\dots, S_m \} $ with each set formed out of any strictly positive number of elements.

For a given number $k$ with $0<k < n$, find the $k$ elements that maximize the number of covered sets.

This problem is similar but not identical to the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) and [maximum coverage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem).

How is this problem called and which algorithm should be used to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For $1 \leq i \leq n$, let $B_i = \{S_j: S_j \in S, x_i \in S_j\}$. Then apply the maximum coverage problem to the sets $B_i$.